# program not running [Error] a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token

Tags: c++, mergesort

Why dont the program go in int main(), i tried before calling void from main function and it doestn have probelems like this: what is wrong?

did i miss something here????

am i wrong with my parameters in the voids????

Why dont the program go in int main(), i tried before calling void from main function and it doestn have probelems like this: what is wrong?

did i miss something here????

am i wrong with my parameters in the voids????

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

 void merge(int array[],int left,int mid,int right){

int lsize = mid + left +1;
int rsize = right - mid;

int larray[lsize];
int rarray[rsize];

for (int i = 0; i < lsize; i++){
    
     larray[i] = array[left + i];
}
   
for (int j = 0; j < rsize; j++){
    
    rarray[j] = array[mid + 1 + j];
}
    
int i=0, j=0, k=left;

 while (i < lsize && j < rsize) {
    if (larray[i] <= rarray[j]) {
        array[k] = larray[i];
        i++;
    }
    else {
        array[k] = rarray[j];
        j++;
    }
    k++;
}

// Copy the remaining elements of
// L[], if there are any
while (i < lsize) {
    array[k] = larray[i];
    i++;
    k++;
}

void sort(int array[], int left,int right){

if(left>=right){
    return;
}
int mid = left + ((right-1)/2);
sort(array[],left,mid)
sort(array[],mid+1,right)
//  merge(array[],left,mid,right);
}

int main()
{
int size;
int x;

cout<<"Enter number of Elements: ";
cin>>size;

int arr[size-1];

cout<<"Enter Elements "<<"("<<size<<"): "<<endl;

for(int i=0; i<size; i++){              
cin>>x;
arr[i]=x;               
}

cout<<"Unosorted Array is: ";

for(int i=0; i<size; i++){              
cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
}

sort(arr,0,size);
        
return 0;   
}
```

Comment: You have a typo in your code. You've an extra brace `}`.

Answer (score 1):

You braces `{` and `}` are mismatched. If you indent your code properly it becomes obvious.

```
while (i < lsize) {
    array[k] = larray[i];
    i++;
    k++;
}

} // added extra } here
```

Always indent your code correctly. It's absolutely vital for writing understandable code. Including you understanding your own code.